# Meaning of transform's area - Fourier

Tags: fourier-transform, fourier

What is the graphic meaning of the transform's area?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{X(f)df}$$

Where $X(f)$ is the continuous Fourier transform of the signal $x(t)$.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implicit $e^{\jmath 2 \pi  f t }$ with $t=0$ in your integral which means it equals $x(0)$.

If $X(f)$ were a probability density instead of a Fourier Transform, it would have an interpretation in the context of the axioms of probability. When you say $graphic$ meaning , the context is somewhat vague. In calculus, the general meaning of an integral without using terms like measure, is the area under the curve, allowing for negative areas for negative values of the function.

Comment: i think what Stanley might be trying to say is that, with the Fourier Transform and inverse defined as $$X(f) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(t) e^{-j2\pi ft} dt \\  x(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} X(f) e^{+j2\pi ft} df $$ in the inverse, if one sets $t=0$ you get simply $$\begin{align} x(0) &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} X(f) e^{+j2\pi f0} df \\ &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} X(f) \, 1 \, df  \end{align}$$

Comment: There are some different conventions for the normalizing factor $1/ 2 \pi$, one is to include it in the inverse transform

Comment: Hi @Stanley Pawlukiewicz, my goal is to understant what kind of area is it on the complex plane. Is an area on complex plane? Is a volume on the complex plane+time axis?

Comment: when angular frequency, $\omega$, is used, there is a factor of $2\pi$ to deal with.

Comment: I think any geometric interpretation would depend on the specific choice of $X(f)$

Comment: rbj. Without seeing the forward transform, $f$ could mean the conventional $f$ or something different.  $f$ is just a dummy variable of integration. Why quibble about notation conversions?

Comment: notational convention is important, in my opinion, to limit confusion.  i wouldn't wanna call "$f$" *angular* frequency.

Comment: How old are you in Martian years.

Comment: A volume in a complex plane time axis space. You should elaborate on that.